# Integrating Javascript functions with Grails application

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm in the process of shifting a web application from a PHP/MySQL backend to the Grails framework.  However, the app has a fair bit of legacy javascript code written for it that I'd like to use with minimal re-writing.  Its currently not working, and I'm not sure why.

A friend wrote a fade out slideshow script that requires an array initialized as

```
var images[3];
images[0] = ['path to image', 'link to somewhere', 'target'];
```

When writing in PHP, I just used the relative path and double quotes for the link and target, ie

```
images[0] = ["../images/file.jpg", "", ""]
```

Shifting to Grails, I want to have the slideshow visible on all pages, thus resuling in insertion in main.gsp.

I've declared the javascript link in the head as

```
<g:javascript src="fade_in.js" />
```

The way the original script worked was the image array was initalized in the script, then passed in via a function call in the body code.  Since I don't know if its possible to use a Grails `createLinkTo` function call in a js file, I initialized the array and called the function with

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var images[3];
        images[0] = ["<g:createLinkTo dir='images' file='nsf.jpg' />", "", ""]
        images[1] = ["<g:createLinkTo dir='images' file='east.jpg'/>", "", ""]
        images[2] = ["<g:createLinkTo dir='images' file='usm_horz.png' />", "", ""]
        new fadeshow(fadeimages,200,118,0,8000,1,"R");                          
  </script>
</div>
```

According to firebug, the paths to the files is correct, but they're not showing up in the specified div position.  I can see where the images should be, and its empty.

So, what needs to be done to integrate this functionality with a Grails app?

Comment: I assume your call to fadeshow passing fadeimages is a typo, since your array is named "images" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use GSP tags in a .js file unless you have mapped the js file as gsp.
You can create a gsp file eg fade_in.gsp that would declare the images array.

Eg - fade_in.gsp

```
<script>
   //you initialize your javascript array here - you can use all gsp tags.
</script>
```

And then include this gsp file in other pages that needs the images array.